# Magento 2 multi Store issue

Tags: magento2, multistore

I am working on Magento ver. 2.1.7 and my document root is /var/www/magento2/ and site URL  http://172.16.60.52/magento2/

In the admin menu Stores -> Settings -> All Store
I have created One Main Website and two store for Electronic and Fashion . Also I have created store view 
for each store having code electronic and fashion respectively.

In the admin section I have set the following configurations

Stores - > Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> (Store View:  Default Config) Add Store Code to Urls - > Yes

**Stores - > Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> (Store View: Electronic)**

Base URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/electronic/

Base Link URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/electronic/

Secure Base URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/electronic/

Secure Base Link URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/electronic/

**Stores - > Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> (Store View:  Fashion)**

Base URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/fashion/

Base Link URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/fashion/

Secure Base URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/fashion/

Secure Base Link URL -> http://172.16.60.52/magento2/fashion/

I have created two directories electronic & fashion in document root, copied index.php and .htaccess files from magento2 directory to electronic and fashion directory

I have change the /var/www/magento2/electronic/index.php file as code given below...

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'electronic';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Also, I have change the `/var/www/magento2/fashion/index.php` file as code given below...

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'fashion';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

While accessing url `http://172.16.60.52/magento2/electronic/` we got the following error

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

> Error log record number: 876098939040

Log file info :

> a:4:{i:0;s:15:"No such entity.";i:1;s:4915:"#0
>   /var/www/magento/ehgsdigi/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/Website.php(46):
>   Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->get('electronic')

...................

Please advice me

Answer (score 0):

Well I've done in another way maybe you are interested...

I've not edited any **index.php** or **.htaccess** file.

I've edited virtual host as below.

**My default website** :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName main-shop.local
  DocumentRoot /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop

  ErrorLog /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/error.log
  CustomLog /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/access.log combined

  <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop>
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**My another website:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName main-shop-test.local
  DocumentRoot /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/pub
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "f2f89c0ef1_146f0ca8f6"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"

  ErrorLog /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/error.log
  CustomLog /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/access.log combined

  <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/mypc/Projects/main-shop/pub>
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In above virtual host I've added my website code and rest magento will do by itself.

Comment: Is there any other solution? Instead of modifying virtual host.